# Make <li> width according to text in it on smaller screens using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this horizontal scrolling tab, where the width of `<li>` items are different. On screens like desktop/laptop, it renders well i.e. width of the `<li>` is according to the text contained in it.

[image]

However, on smaller screens like mobile phones, `<li>` items with larger width breaks as shown in the image below. This does not look nice. I want the look to be consistent on all the screens like in the first image.

[image]

How can I achieve this? I have tried several solutions found in the SO but it didn't help me.
Please help me. My complete CSS is:

```
.nav-tabs {
display: inline-flex;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
-ms-overflow-style: none; /*// IE 10+*/
overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;/*// Firefox*/
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
    border-width: 0;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a {
    border: none;
    color: #666;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
    border: none;
    color: #4285F4 !important;
    background: transparent;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a::after {
    content: "";
    background: #4285F4;
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 1px;
    transition: all 250ms ease 0s;
    transform: scale(0);
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a::after,
.nav-tabs>li:hover>a::after {
    transform: scale(1);
}
.tab-nav>li>a::after {
    background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    color: #fff;
}
.tab-pane {
    padding: 15px 0;
}
.tab-content {
    padding: 20px
}

.nav-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; /*Safari and Chrome*/
}
.card {
    background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .nav-tabs > li {
            dispaly: inline;
        }    
    }
```

My HTML is:

```
<div class="card">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Animation</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Computers</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tutorials</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kids Special Course</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#about" aria-controls="about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Spoken English</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" aria-controls="contact" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Coding</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
            <legend>Responsive Tabs</legend>
            <p>If you are on desktop Try resizing the window to mobile view to see the scroll effect</p>
            <p>Horizontal scrollable tabs</p>
            <p>Best for mobile view</p>
            <p>Similar to gravity MODE_SCROLLABLE in Android</p>
          </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
                <legend>Profile</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">
                <legend>Messages</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">
                <legend>Settings</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passage..</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="about">
                <legend>About</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passage..</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="contact">
                <legend>Contact Us</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passage..</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using Bootstrap 3 (Doing some modifications in an old project)

Comment: Make it display block

Answer (score 0):

To make text in one row, add "white-space: nowrap;" to anchor (**.nav-tabs>li>a**). This will prevent text break. See CSS changes.

```css
.nav-tabs {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /*// IE 10+*/
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;
  /*// Firefox*/
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  border-width: 0;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a {
  border: none;
  color: #666;
  white-space: nowrap; /* add this */
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border: none;
  color: #4285F4 !important;
  background: transparent;
}

.nav-tabs>li>a::after {
  content: "";
  background: #4285F4;
  height: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 1px;
  transition: all 250ms ease 0s;
  transform: scale(0);
}

.nav-tabs>li.active>a::after,
.nav-tabs>li:hover>a::after {
  transform: scale(1);
}

.tab-nav>li>a::after {
  background: #21527d none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  color: #fff;
}

.tab-pane {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.tab-content {
  padding: 20px
}

.nav-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
  /*Safari and Chrome*/
}

.card {
  background: #FFF none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .nav-tabs>li {
    dispaly: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="card">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Animation</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Computers</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tutorials</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Kids Special Course</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#about" aria-controls="about" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Spoken English</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact" aria-controls="contact" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Coding</a></li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">
      <legend>Responsive Tabs</legend>
      <p>If you are on desktop Try resizing the window to mobile view to see the scroll effect</p>
      <p>Horizontal scrollable tabs</p>
      <p>Best for mobile view</p>
      <p>Similar to gravity MODE_SCROLLABLE in Android</p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">
      <legend>Profile</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book.</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">
      <legend>Messages</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
      recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">
      <legend>Settings</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passage..</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="about">
      <legend>About</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
      specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passage..</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="contact">
      <legend>Contact Us</legend>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
      It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passage..</div>
  </div>
</div>
```